# NullReferenceException when Assigning String to ViewModel

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, nullreferenceexception

I'm experiencing the error `NullReferenceException was unhandled by user code` followed by `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` I've read a number of questions including the very detailed answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4660186/2075402) but can't understand why.

The line is occurring on the line `vm.HomeView.ComputerName = Environment.MachineName;`

When the error occurs, `Environemnt.MachineName` is correctly showing the machines name as expected so there is definitely a string variable trying to be assigned.

Could anyone help explain why.

**Controller:**

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    InventoryLogViewModel vm = new InventoryLogViewModel();

    vm.HomeView.ComputerName = Environment.MachineName;
    vm.HomeView.RACFID = Environment.UserName;

    vm.AssetTypes = (from at in db.AssetTypes
                     orderby at.Name
                     select new AssetType
                     {
                         AssetTypeId = at.AssetTypeId,
                         Name = at.Name
                     }).ToList();

    return View(vm);
```

**ViewModel:**

```
namespace ControlsTeam.Models
{
    public class InventoryLogViewModel : _LayoutViewModel
    {
        public IEnumerable<Department> Departments { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<AssetType> AssetTypes { get; set; }
        public Inventory Inventory { get; set; }
        public HomeView HomeView { get; set; }
    }

    public class HomeView
    {
        public string RACFID { get; set; }
        public string ComputerName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to learn to debug your code. If `vm.HomeView` is null (you have not initialized it anywhere) then that exception will be thrown. Suggest you include a parameterless constructor in `InventoryLogViewModel` that initializes properties `HomeVew`, Inventory` `AssetTypes and `Departments`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How, given this code:

```
InventoryLogViewModel vm = new InventoryLogViewModel();
```

could `vm.HomeView` (as used on the next line) be anything else then `null` ?

The `InventoryLogViewModel` constructor does not have an implementation, so its `HomeView` member after construction can only be `null`.

You may want to do the following:

```
InventoryLogViewModel vm = new InventoryLogViewModel() {
   HomeView = new HomeView() {
       RACFID = Environment.UserName,
       ComputerName = Environment.MachineName
   }
};
```

Comment: Oh jeez, well I feel like a bit of a idiot. It's late here in England. Thanks!